# How to start multiple threads in Julia?

Tags: multithreading, julia

I use Julia1.7 under Windows 10 and to start multiple threads according to the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/) I should do:

```
$ julia --threads 4
```

Where should I enter such command? When I start Julia the environment looks like:
[image]

It does not have the `$` sign.

Comment: I believe this should be done when starting. From your post, I think you don't run Julia from the shell? Either you run it from the shell using the above parameter, or there might be an option when starting the application (that then starts Julia)?

Comment: yes, the thread parameter is to be given to start Julia, not from within Julia. If you use VSCode (with the Julia extension) it automatically starts Julia with 4 threads

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't set the number of threads in an already running Julia session. As the comments suggests, you should pass the `--threads` flag to `julia` when starting, i.e. the command is entered in your shell (if you're on Windows most likely PowerShell, or the new Windows Terminal, or cmd).

If you are using either of the VSCode Julia extension or Juno (the older, Atom based Julia IDE) there are settings which allow you to choose the number of threads. A screenshot from VSCode settings:

[image]

Alternatively, threads can be set in `settings.json`, where an entry like

```
"julia.NumThreads": "auto"
```

should be added.

When using Jupyter notebooks through `IJulia`, you can register a kernel with multiple threads by doing

```
julia> using IJulia

julia> installkernel("Julia (4 threads)", env = Dict("JULIA_NUM_THREADS" => "4"))
```

When working in Pluto notebooks, you can set the number of threads when starting the notebook like so:

```
Pluto.run(threads=16)
```

Comment: Where in the vscode settings did you find Num Threads?

Comment: Looks like the GUI has changed slightly - probably easiest to just set it in `settings.json`, have edited the answer above to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the shell variable JULIA_NUM_THREADS, and set it equal to the number of threads that you want.